# Is there a nice naming convention for nonempty lists in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, naming

For example, if I have a list of names `names :: [Text]`, and I construct a `NonEmpty Text` from it, I could call it `neNames`, `names'`, `namesNonEmpty`. Is there a standard (preferably short) convention for this?

A silly question, I know, but I'd like to know people's opinions on this. Naming is, after all, one of the two hard problems in computer science.

**Edit:** Apparently I'm not allowed to ask for people's opinions. However, the rest of the question still stands. Whether or not there is a standard convention for this is certainly something for which it is possible to provide citations.

Comment: I don't imagine I'd be keeping both of them in active use in the same scope, so wouldn't need the variable name to instantly convey "this is the one with `NonEmpty` type" (the other one being also nonempty, just stored in a regular list)". I'd just call it `names` (and use a prime or something if the other one was still technically in scope). Conventions like `x:xs` are more about conveying relationships and usage than they are types. If I need it to be clear that `names` is a `NonEmpty`, I'd prefer to write that explicitly with a type annotation, rather than put a mnemonic in the name.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of, but you might be able to borrow the convention from monadic parsers of using a `1` suffix to identify "at least one".  We have `sepBy` and `endBy` when parsing zero or more things, and `sepBy1` and `endBy1` when parsing one or more things.

So, `names` and `names1` might do it.

Ideally, you would try to design your datatypes so that you never have to name `names` at all, if an empty list of names indicates an invalid state, though I understand you might be validating an existing data structure where `names` can be empty into a new data structure where `names1` must be non-empty.